# Using Javascript/JQuery and getting undefined var when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Javascript/JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    name = $("#name").val();

    alert("Name: " + name);

</script>
```

And this HTML:

```
<form name="report" action="send.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Senna" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />

</form>
```

When the page loads i get "Name: undefined" instead of "Name: Senna".

Can someone help me to get the expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of everything ever...

Comment: Well... you make this mistake only once... better to get it out the way...

Comment: @Lix, You're right, as i am in my first steps with JQuery, this mistake i certainly won't make anymore

Comment: It really is the key to allowing you to get going with jQuery - good luck, happy coding and have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

You need to indicate to execute the function once the page has been loaded.  Currently you are only defining it and not  decalring when to execute it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    name = $('#name').val();
    alert('Name: ' + name);
});
```

Or:

```
$(function(){
    name = $('#name').val();
    alert('Name: ' + name);
});
```

Comment: Very objetive your explanation! Thanks for the attention and patience!

Comment: Glad I could assist.  I've learned over the years that providing the appropriate amount of details is very helpful in determining any solution.  After all, it's hard to solve a problem if you don't understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You should place your code inside the [DOM ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    alert("Name: " + name);
});
```

Otherwise you are trying the work with elements which are not yet loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `document.ready` callback.

Place your code inside a function like this -

```
$(function(){
  // code goes here
});
```

You need to use this callback to know when jQuery *and* the entire DOM is loaded.  Only then can you start to manipulate the Markup and CSS with your jQuery code.

---

The code above is really just shorthand for this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // code goes here
});
```

This uses the `.ready()` method - http://api.jquery.com/ready/
An extract from the description of the `.ready()` function -

> ... The handler passed to `.ready()` is guaranteed to be executed after
>   the DOM is ready, so this is usually **the best place to attach all
>   other event handlers and run other jQuery code.** ...

<sub>emphasis added</sub>